# Handler class code not firing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I am learning to use Handlers in ASP.NET.

I added Web Form and changed the extension to "*.bspx".

I added a class with code like this:

```
    namespace Experiments1
    {

    public class UniqueHandler: IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains(".bspx"))
            {
                string newUrl = context.Request.RawUrl.Replace(".bspx", ".aspx");
                context.Server.Transfer(newUrl);
            }

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

I added below lines in web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.bspx" name="Uniquehandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

The page "default.aspx" has a Link Button with postback URL set to open the above page.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" PostBackUrl="~/DifferentPage.bspx" runat="server" Text="Bspx"></asp:LinkButton>
```

But when I click the above link button, it shows error:

```
The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/DifferentPage.bspx' is not allowed.
```

** Edited **
Web.Config code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LearnConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Learn;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LearnConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Learn;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.bspx" type="UniqueHandler, App_Code" name="Uniquehandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please check "bspx" or "aspx" ?

Comment: Intentionally done .bspx to create a handler to handle .bspx page.

Comment: Does `UniqueHandler` really not have a namespace? If it has, you  need to put the fully qualified name into `web.config`.

Comment: @GoloRoden Edited the post. It does have a namespace.

Comment: @RKh- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx please check whether your format is correct or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed `type` in webconfig file ,

```
 <add verb="*" path="*.bspx" type="UniqueHandler, App_Code" name="Uniquehandler"/>
```

Here is the "`App_Code`" code means your class file folder name.

**Edit** :

Here is my solution file details

[image]

Here is my  uniqueHanlder class code from App-data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for UniqueHandler
/// </summary>
public class UniqueHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public UniqueHandler()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains(".bspx"))
        {
            string newUrl = context.Request.RawUrl.Replace(".bspx", ".aspx");
            context.Server.Transfer(newUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my default.aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" Text="xxx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>           
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" PostBackUrl="~/Default2.bspx" runat="server" Text="Bspx"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my web.config file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.bspx" **type="UniqueHandler, App_Code"** name="Uniquehandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nope It's working on me!  The `UniqueHandler` in App-Code folder?

Comment: Can you give your mail id ? I will send my sample working application.

Comment: I moved the UniqueHandler class in App_Code folder and also did changes as you suggested above, but still not working. Rechecking ...

Comment: I also put brack point in my class, The class is called and i have not seen any error.

Comment: Please post your Web.Config code. I rechecked the changes and everything is similar to the code you suggested. I am using VS2010.

Comment: Also Post the web.config file. That's not a problem

Comment: Please change `targetFramework="4.0"` to  `targetFramework="4.5"`

Comment: And also you have missed ` <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>`

Comment: TargetFramework 4.5 is not applicable as I am using 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I think it's may be a IIS issue

Comment: Yes I think it is IIS issue. I tried on VS2013, but getting error: Could not load type 'UniqueHandler' from assembly 'App_Code'.  Anyway, I am giving this bounty to you.

Comment: I think now the handler class not be there in app-code folder , please now verify my whole answer with solution file :) happy coding